# How to ping the mysql server in Yii2 Framework

Tags: mysql, yii2

I am looking to be able to ping the MySQL server using `mysql_ping()` (`mysqli_ping()`) inside the Yii2 Framework.

I currently use the `createCommand()` for all my SQL queries so I do not have a good understanding of how to use the ping function outside of that scope.

I am not sure how to even grab the SQL link inside go Yii.

I do not have any test code since I am not even sure where to start.

Any help to point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: look here https://terenceyim.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/adding-ping-function-to-pdo/

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply.  Hello Terry, the problem I am having is during a looped insert of just a few hundred records on a daily basis, the loop is failing on random days with no error message thru CRON, except for one time I got a glimpse of an error stating the mysql server went away.  As a diagnostic I wanted to include a 'ping' of some sort to determine if I am indeed losing my server.

Answer (score 2):

Yii DB component uses PDO, which does not have `mysql_ping()` equivalent. The closest what you can get is to query `SELECT 1` and reconnect if exception occurred.

```
public function ping() {
    try {
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT 1')->query();
    } catch (\yii\db\Exception $exception) {
        Yii::$app->db->close();
        Yii::$app->db->open();
    }
}
```

Note that reconnection implicitly may result unexpected and silent rollbacks if you're using transactions.

Comment: also if looking to using `PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS`, then  `$db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS)` keeps replying "Localhost via UNIX socket" even after stopping mysqld.

Comment: Thanks rob006, I think you turned on the light bulb.  For some reason I never put in any code to catch that exception.